# How could a broken link in our homepage impact our user experience?

Tags: landing-page, testimonials

By visiting [WinAutomation](http://www.winautomation.com/) you will notice a broken link in the testimonials.
While being a very easy fix you could do in less than 1 minute it is left like that for several months now.
What impact would you think it would have to the user who happens to try and follow the link?

Comment: As it stands this question would count as a Site Review which is off topic on UX Se. Could you narrow it to a question about a specific part of the interface or a particular tactic you're thinking of implementing to increase conversion. That way the question will be useful to others on the site.

Comment: This question is fictional because I just wanted to share knowledge QnA style. It is related to testimonials. So how would you recommend to rephrase it for this specific issue?

Comment: I would perhaps rephrase it to inquire about the customer impact of testimonials or seeing your answer, how a broken link in testimonials impacts trust (i.e. do they regard it as a typo/coding glitch or do they think you're lying and gives the perception of deceit)

Answer (score 1):

Humans by nature are visual creatures, the page is informative but very text heavy. Where an average unique visitor will spend around 5-20 seconds looking whether or not he/she will proceed to further explore other pages of the site, the front page is way too cluttered to do so now, unless I know specifically why I came to this site. Breaking down the text with some imagery and interaction will increase the likelihood of your visitors further engagement.

Answer (score 0):

You have a nice look and feel in your landing page but first and foremost is to build **trust** with your users in every corner of your product.

Trust can be easily lost and in your case I see that in one of the testimonials the link, [www.FetterGroup.com](http://www.FetterGroup.com), returns a *403 Forbidden* response.
This lowers the credibility a lot!
I have witnessed many users being suspicious of testimonials and you should try extra hard to show them otherwise.

Comment: did you just ask and answered your own question? haha

Comment: Yes Q n A style to share knowledge as this platform supports. I hope I did it to look like a real question and answer. However you are correct to the part that people find it strange when they see someone post like that but the need to share knowledge somehow, within the platform, remains. Perhaps there is a design opportunity here..

Comment: right on man! interesting